# getting javascript packs to load after XHR response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

A Rails 6 application has an XHR response that contains two links

```
<%= link_to t('transaction.new').capitalize, new_transaction_path(consumer_id: user.id), class: 'button' %>
<%= link_to t('user.link_card').capitalize, link_card_user_path(id: user.id), class: 'button' %>
```

Both links are not remote postings. Yet in practice they generate a subsequent XHR GET response.
[image: XHR GET response]
The server logs an HTML request.

```
Started GET "/users/2579/link_card" for ::1 at 2021-02-18 17:39:32 +0100
Processing by UsersController#link_card as HTML
```

It renders the HTML template for the full page, but without the packs/js blocks.  The latter is a problem as the javascript is required to run the planned operations in the action.

If the page is reloaded all objects related to the action are rendered
[image: objects rendered]

How can the link ensure that the action undertaken is the full GET request and not be interpreted as an XHR?

Answer (score 0):

This is a turbolinks issue.  Wrapping the `link_to` elements in a tag that disables turbolinks resolves the problem.

```
  <div data-turbolinks='false'>
   ...
  </div>
```